# ios sqlite3 database no such table on certain ios versions only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have a curious problem with my sqlite3 database.

It works in the simulator on the following versions:

- ipad 2 ios 8.4 ipad
- retina ios 8.4
- iphone 4 ios 8.4
- iphone 5 ios 8.4
- iphone 6 ios
  8.4

**But it does not work on ipad Air ios 8.4**  and I receive the error no such table favourites
Similarly I have tested across ios 8.1 and it works in all the devices except iphone 5, but it does work in ios 5s

My sql database file looks like this when I open it in TextEdit

```
 SQLite format 3@  -Ê
mmÅ!!ÅktablefavouritesfavouritesCREATE TABLE favourites(favouriteID integer primary key, tomhaisID integer, tomhaisText text, answered integer)
```

I created the database from the console, it is only when I open the file that I see those extra characters:  When in SQLite3 mode in the console I entered the Create Table command like this:

```
`CREATE TABLE favourites(favouriteID integer primary key, tomhaisID integer, tomhaisText text, answered integer);`
```

Any ideas why I am seeing this inconsistent behaviour?

My DBManager file looks like this:

```
    //
//  DBManager.m
//  Facts
//
//  Created by Linda Keating on 28/05/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 LindaKeating. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DBManager.h"

@interface DBManager()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentsDirectory;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseFilename;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrResults;

-(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable;
-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory;

@end

@implementation DBManager

-(instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

        [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{

    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        NSString *sourePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];


        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}

-(void) runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable{
    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;

    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

    if (self.arrResults != nil) {
        [self.arrResults removeAllObjects];
        self.arrResults = nil;
    }

    self.arrResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (self.arrColumnNames != nil) {
        [self.arrColumnNames removeAllObjects];
        self.arrColumnNames = nil;
    }

    self.arrColumnNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
        if (prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {

            if (!queryExecutable) {

                NSMutableArray *arrDataRow;

                while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    arrDataRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    int totalColumns = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);

                    for (int i=0; i<totalColumns; i++) {
                        char *dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i);

                        if (dbDataAsChars != NULL) {
                            [arrDataRow addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                        }

                        if (self.arrColumnNames.count != totalColumns) {
                            dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_name(compiledStatement, i);
                            [self.arrColumnNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                        }
                    }

                    if (arrDataRow.count >0) {
                        [self.arrResults addObject:arrDataRow];
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
              //  BOOL executeQueryResults = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)== SQLITE_DONE) {
                    self.affectedRows = sqlite3_changes(sqlite3Database);
                    self.lastInsertedRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3Database);
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
}

-(NSArray *)loadDataFromDB:(NSString *)query{
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:NO];
    return (NSArray *)self.arrResults;
}

-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query{
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: 1. Try to run 'release' mode instead of 'debug'. I don't think this is device dependent but rather connected with timing. What are the results? Same? (don't forget to completely remove the app) 2. Did you try to put the breakpoint? Maybe openDatabaseResult or queryExecutable is set to NO. Also it's convenient to use FMDB to handle raw sql databases, you'll skip many eventual failures later.

Comment: Hi Vive, running in release mode works.  thanks for the help.  I'm wondering if you have time maybe you could help me understand why this has worked?  I'll also have a look into FMDB - thanks again.

Comment: In debug the execution process is slower (you may imagine that we're printing all logs to the console and watch the attributes, breakpoints etc). So your code have more time to execute each step. In this case, in certain situations your table could not be added when you've been checking it. Do notice, that this is still a bug and still needs fixing, you cannot expect that it will run always properly in release mode. In case of some background work you may have less resources and the code won't work. You need to fix it. Running proper code with FMDB will help you to easily fix the issue.

Comment: I'm converting the comments to the answer. If you have any further questions feel free to ask under that question, even about FMDB :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is device dependent but rather connected with timing.

1. Try to run `release` mode instead of `debug`.
2. Did you try to put the breakpoint? Maybe `openDatabaseResult` or `queryExecutable` is set to `NO`.

What are the results? Same? (don't forget to completely remove the app)

Also it's convenient to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to handle raw sql databases, you'll skip many eventual failures later.

Explantation:

In the debug mode the execution process is slower (you may imagine that we're printing all logs to the console and watch the attributes, breakpoints etc). So your code have more time to execute each step. In this case, in certain situations your table could not be added when you've been checking it (out of sync, you firstly read then save, because saving is slower).

Do notice, that this is still a bug and still needs fixing, you cannot expect that it will run always properly in release mode. In case of some background work you may have less resources and the code won't work. You need to fix it.

Running proper code with FMDB will help you to easily fix the issue, as they have transactions and other elements which help you to keep integrity of the data.